# Download released asset from private github repo

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to download a single added asset from a release in a private repository but all I get is a 404 response. the download url of the asset is `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/releases/download/20211022/file.json`

I've tried several different methods of specifying the username and private access token but all give the same result. When I use the access token to access api.github.com then it seems to work.

I've tried the following formats in curl

```
curl -i -u <user>:<token> <url>
curl -i "https://<user>:<token>@github.com/ ...."
curl -i -H "Authorization: token <token>" <url>
```

I **can** download the source code (zip) from the release, but this has a different url: `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/archive/refs/tags/20211022.zip`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in this [document](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/assets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-release-asset).

You have to use `url: /repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/assets/{asset_id}` not `browser_download_url` and set request header to accept `application/octet-stream` to download.
And don't forget to add `Authorization` header too.

[1]:

Comment: Thanks, the Accept header did the trick!

Comment: FYI: Everyone should keep in mind that this endpoint can redirect. A Location header will be returned with the new location. Make sure you follow redirects.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to use the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation), with the command [`gh release download`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_download).

Since [`gh` 2.19.0 (Nov. 2022)](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.19.0), you can download a single asset with `gh release download --output` (after a [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login), for authentication):

In your case:

```
gh release download --pattern 'file.json' --output file.json
```